# Incorrect Identification of Target Branch - SystemPullRequestTargetBranch. What is the workaround?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, environment-variables, azure-pipelines-yaml

~[image]

System variable `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` cannot be used in templates. What is the workaround for below.

[image: YAML file]

[image: using Environment dev this wrongly mapped instead of PROD]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends where you want to use `Environment` variable. If in deployment job to set environment, you can't as it has to be known at compilation time.

If you want to use in place which can be established at runtime, you can use logging command to setup variable.

```
- pwsh: |
    if ( 'refs/heads/release-uat' -in @('$(Build.SourceBranch)','$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)') )
    {
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Environment;]uat"
    }
```

However, variable set in that way can't be use in some places.

Comment: using Environment dev this wrongly mapped instead of PROD. Please find the snapshot attachment in the question.